# Google Docs Approvals API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is there API access to the Google Docs Approvals functionality (accessed via File > Approvals)? I would like to trigger the Approvals workflow via integrators like Zapier or Make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no actual functionality for this feature through the API however you may want to start this [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/208025958) that is requesting this feature to be added. You may want to add yourself your reasoning about why this feature would be a good fit to the API that way Google's team may consider the feature request in the near future.